# how to prove $T(n) \le 2^{n-1}$ , $T(n)$ is the number of way that write n as the sum of 1's and 2's

Tags: discrete-mathematics

how to prove $T(n) \le 2^{n-1}$ , $T(n)$ is the number of way that write n as the sum of 1's and 2's

such as n = 3, T(n) =3, because 3 = 1+1+1, 3=1+2 ,3 =2+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  Notice that since we are counting ordered partitions, and the first term is either $1$ or $2$, we have the recurrence $$T(n+1)=T(n)+T(n-1).$$  From here you could solve the recurrence or use induction.

Comment: As an aside, you need to prove 2 base cases if you are to use induction here.